# Problem while implementing HttpSessionLister with Spring-Security

Tags: java, session, spring-security

I am using Spring/Hibernate and Spring-Security for my web-based application. Now I have a requirement where I need to perform some database query at sessionDestroy method of HtppSessionLister.

Inside web.xml :

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.test.TestSessionListner</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

With my implementation, after session timeout (of 1 min), its calling the sessionDestroyed method and fetching the required Object of **TestFacade** from the **ApplicationContext**.

Now my problem is whenever I am calling the following method using userFacade, its not able to execute the code inside the method :

```
Person person = testFacade.findPersonByUserId(userId);
```

How can I identify the root cause for this?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "its not able to execute the code inside the method"? is the method not returning from execution? or is it returning null?

Comment: @asgs : means its not able to call that particular method, though userFacade object has been initialized.

Comment: So, what does the SOP print? Try debugging the application to see if `userFacade` is initialized and steps into that method in question. Also, examine the return value.

Comment: @asgs : well, its initializing the userFacade, but not able to call the findPersonByUserId method. Observed that on function calling line, its calling session.invalidate() internal JDK method directly. Also Nothing gets printed with SOP.

Comment: How do you get `userId`?

Comment: @Raghuram : Sorry, forgot to copy that line.. Updated the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue....

Inside `sessionDestroyed` I was calling a method :

```
Person person = testFacade.findPersonIdByUserId(userId);
```

which needs some higher permissions then `anonymousUser` to execute the method, and at `sessionDestroyed` its clearing the existing user and calling `sessionDestroyed` method with `anonymousUser` permission.

So finally I have written a code, which is calling a method using **Administrator** writes.